# Is it possible to claim EI while contracting

Tags: canada, incorporating, employment-insurance

My friend has been terminated from a full-time job recently by his employer due to Work Force Reduction. He is eligible to apply for claiming Employment Insurance from next month.

Meanwhile he got a contracting job for 6 months. He decided not to pay for himself from the contract job and leave the money earned in business account.

Can he claim EI until he finds a full-time job?

Comment: What kind of business account?  I don't know the categories in Canada, but in the US, that could refer to a sole proprietorship, an LLC, or a C-Corp among other options.  It may make something of a difference.  You also might want to include province in case the rules are different.  E.g. if provincially incorporated.

Comment: Its a provincial incorporation in Ontario

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, your friend would not be eligible for EI under these conditions. In order to claim EI, your friend must certify they are ["ready, willing, and capable of working each day"](https://www.canada.ca/en/employment-social-development/programs/ei/ei-list/reports/regular-benefits/eligibilty.html). As your friend is doing contract work, even though they are not drawing money, they do not meet the criteria.

Claiming EI while working a contracting job would be fraud, and is most definitely not what EI is there for.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to claim EI after completing 6 months contract and until he find a full-time job?

Comment: I'm uncertain about that case. The EI office would be able to tell you. I suspect the answer is yes, but I'm not remotely sure about that.